# How import private key to Keplr extension

Tags: metamask

I export the private key from metamask then import to Keplr wallet.

But the new wallet got diff address with the old one in metamask.

So how can I do in this case?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I did this import with ONE to Metamask staking.one read the ONE address even though it had a different address displayed in Metamask on the EVM side.  Check the block chain explorer to verify funds and move a tiny amount for proof of function